# TYPO3 New folder/page not showing

Tags: visibility, typo3-6.2.x

I have a FAQ-page with different categories and FAQ's respectively that works. Now, when I want to add a new category (folder) and/or new FAQ's (sites displayed as links) it doesn't show on the frontend.

I think I tried everything so far. I even duplicated another folder so that I definitely have the same properties for my new folder, and renamed it. Doesn't work either. Also, I can't rename old folders. It just doesn't show.

Comment: how do you store your FAQs and how do you display your FAQs?This sounds like you edit records, and the plugin/ the page with the plugin to show the records does not get informed and cleared caches.

Comment: I don't quite know how to answer this, since I am only trying to add a folder/site to the site tree in the backend.

Comment: a new page will not render anything by default, so it is neccessary to have some typoscript to fill in content. either special typoscript to get specific content for this page, or general typoscript to render some contentelements (CEs) which were added to this page. These CEs either have all data (e.g. Text) or they access some records (e.g. of an extension) to show their content (e.g. news-plugin). Please provide the active typoscript configuration and (in case it is used) the extension/plugin configuration.